# Using R to merge many large CSV files across sub-directories

Tags: r, csv

I have over 300 large CSV files with the same filename, each in a separate sub-directory, that I would like to merge into a single dataset using R. I'm asking for help on how to remove columns I don't need in each CSV file, while merging in a way that breaks the process down into smaller chunks that my memory can more easily handle.

My objective is to create a single CSV file that I can then import into STATA for further analysis using code I have already written and tested on one of these files.

Each of my CSVs is itself rather large (about 80 columns, many of which are unnecessary, and each file has tens to hundreds of thousands of rows), and there are almost 16 million observations in total, or roughly 12GB.

I have written some code which manages to do this successfully for a test case of two CSVs. The challenge is that neither my work nor my personal computers have enough memory to do this for all 300+ files.

The code I have tried is here:

```
library(here) ##installs package to find files

( allfiles = list.files(path = here("data"), ##creates a list of the files, read as [1], [2], ... [n]
                        pattern = "candidates.csv", ##[identifies the relevant files]
                        full.names = TRUE, ##identifies the full file name
                        recursive = TRUE) ) ##searches in sub-directories

read_fun = function(path) {
  test = read.csv(path,
                  header = TRUE ) 
  test
} ###reads all the files

(test = read.csv(allfiles,
                 header = TRUE ) )###tests that file [1] has been read

library(purrr) ###installs package to unlock map_dfr

library(dplyr) ###installs packages to unlock map_dfr

( combined_dat = map_dfr(allfiles, read_fun) )
```

I expect the result to be a single RDS file, and this works for the test case. Unfortunately, the amount of memory this process requires when looking at 15.5m observations across all my files causes RStudio to crash, and no RDS file is produced.

I am looking for help on how to 1) reduce the load on my memory by stripping out some of the variables in my CSV files I don't need (columns with headers `junk1`, `junk2`, etc); and 2) how to merge in a more manageable way that merges my CSV files in sequence, either into a few RDS files to themselves be merged later, or through a loop cumulatively into a single RDS file.

However, I don't know how to proceed with these - I am still new to R, and any help on how to proceed with both 1) and 2) would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Twelve GB is quite a bit for one object. It's probably not practical to use a single RDS or CSV unless you have far more than 12GB of RAM. You might want to look into using a [database](https://db.rstudio.com/), a techology that is made for this kind of thing. I'm sure Stata can also interact with databases. You might also want to read up on how to interact with large CSVs using [various strategies and packages](https://rpubs.com/msundar/large_data_analysis).

Creating a large CSV isn't at all difficult. Just remember that you have to work with said giant CSV sometime in the future, which probably will be difficult. To create a large CSV, just process each component CSV individually and then append them to your new CSV. The following reads in each CSV, removes unwanted columns, and then appends the resulting dataframe to a flat file:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(purrr)

load_select_append <- function(path) {
    # Read in CSV. Let every column be of class character.
    df <- read_csv(path, col_types = paste(rep("c", 82), collapse = ""))

    # Remove variables beginning with "junk"
    df <- select(df, -starts_with("junk"))

    # If file exists, append to it without column names, otherwise create with
    # column names.
    if (file.exists("big_csv.csv")) {
        write_csv(df, "big_csv.csv", col_names = F, append = T)
    } else {
        write_csv(df, "big_csv.csv", col_names = T)
    }
}


# Get the paths to the CSVs.
csv_paths <- list.files(path = "dir_of_csvs",
                        pattern = "\\.csv.*",
                        recursive = T, 
                        full.names = T
                        )

# Apply function to each path.
walk(csv_paths, load_select_append)
```

When you're ready to work with your CSV you might want to consider using something like the `ff` package, which enables interaction with on-disk objects. You are somewhat restricted in what you can do with an `ffdf` object, so eventually you'll have to work with samples:

```r
library(ff)

df_ff <- read.csv.ffdf(file = "big_csv.csv")
df_samp <- df_ff[sample.int(nrow(df_ff), size = 100000),]
df_samp <- mutate(df_samp, ID = factor(ID))

summary(df_samp)

#### OUTPUT ####

     values             ID       
 Min.   :-9.861   17267  :    6  
 1st Qu.: 6.643   19618  :    6  
 Median :10.032   40258  :    6  
 Mean   :10.031   46804  :    6  
 3rd Qu.:13.388   51269  :    6  
 Max.   :30.465   52089  :    6  
                  (Other):99964
```

As far as I know, chunking and on-disk interactions are not possible with RDS or RDA, so you are stuck with flat files (or you go with one of the other options I mentioned above).